# How to get page index of smart table in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I have a smart table like

```
<table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="FloorData" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="7" class="text-center">                                                                
       <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="10"></div>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

I need to get current page index of this table in angular js file.
How can i do some operations while page index changes?

Answer (score 2):

you can bind a callback to subscribe on page change.

```
<div st-pagination st-page-change="onPageChange(newPage)"></div>
```

Comment: Can u define onPageChange function

Comment: Just a function exposed by your controller scope. You can see it in the unit test https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/blob/master/test/spec/stPagination.spec.js#L463 (the function is a mock). Note if you need it only as a value for your pagination, the porperty "currentPage" is available in the pagination scope